# TKey from OrderBy

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to create a function that recieve one parameter:
1. delegate that get any MyObj instance and returns a key (like OrderBy method).

So I can do the following:

```
function IQueryable<Worker> doSomething(Func<Worker, TKey> getter) {
    Workers.Where(x=>getter(x)==9);
}
```

This method should work with the entity framework. TKey is not defind. How can I do it?

Comment: Is `TKey` intended to be akin to 'RecordID'?

Comment: I doubt you can get that to work with EF since it has to be able to convert your entire expression to sql, how is it supposed to handle your func?

Comment: @IAbstract: For the purphse of the question, TKey can be Id, CompanyId, Age and any other numeric value.

Comment: @alun: I can do 'Workers.Where(x=>x.Id==9);' or 'Workers.Where(x=>x.Age==9);' using the entity framework. I want to mage the x.[...] general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare it to a specific type, like an integer, just use that type in the signature:

```
public IQueryable<Worker> doSomething(Func<Worker, int> getter) {
  Workers.Where(x => getter(x) == 9);
}
```

Otherwise you would have to include it as a generic type and provide a value of that type for the comparison:

```
public IQueryable<Worker> doSomething<TKey>(Func<Worker, TKey> getter, TKey value) {
  Workers.Where(x => getter(x).Equals(value));
}
```

Comment: I believe you mean '... doSomething<TKey>(...)'.

Comment: @Naor: Why did you accept this answer? Did you test the code? It's impossible that this works with LINQ to Entities - even double impossible: LINQ to Entities cannot work with an arbitrary function `getter` in an expression and also `Equals` isn't supported for an arbitrary type of `TKey`. It only works for some primitive types.

Comment: @Slauma: I have long way until I can test this, and if it won't work I'll find a solution. Besides, I only use primitive types.